# Can't disable adaptive brightness

Tags: intel-graphics, dell-latitude

I have a dell latitude 3410 laptop with intel i7 10510u CPU and windows 10 pro 20H2. This device has an adaptive brightness feature (windows feature I guess) I don't like it at all. So I tried to disable it in many ways but failed. Here are the methods I tried:

1. I tried to disable it under power settings on the control panel but here is what I got: [Power plans](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvwW5.png)
   [Power plan settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3nFw.png)
   That is, there is no power plan other than balanced, and there is no setting for adaptive brightness in the advanced options of the plan. So I tried these commands on cmd to add the other plans but it did not work:
   (Power saver)
   "powercfg -duplicatescheme a1841308-3541-4fab-bc81-f71556f20b4a"
   (High Performance)
   "powercfg -duplicatescheme 8c5e7fda-e8bf-4a96-9a85-a6e23a8c635c"
2. I tried the intel graphics command centre but there is no power options section there.[intel command centre](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANKrY.png) I tried to reinstall the graphics driver but nothing has changed.
3. I tried to disable adaptive brightness service in services.msc but there was no service with that name.

Comment: I think Dell has a BIOS settingbto disable it. It annoyed me too.

Comment: Yes it is in the BIOS settings. Thank you very much dude, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is in the BIOS settings.

Click on the display option in the left menu and disable the ecopower option on the screen that appears.

Thanks to [Aganju](https://superuser.com/users/527713/aganju) for their comment.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen a lot of answers attempting to address this problem that did not work for me. I have an HP Envy with Windows 10 and this is what did work for me.

1. Go to the device manager, find the Display drivers, and disable the Intel graphics driver.
2. Go to regedit or the Windows Registry Editor and do a global search for brightnessoverride. Mine was in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\SideBySIde\Winners\amd64_microsoft-windows-g..-brightnessoverride...[some value here].
   2a. Open the Default Value and change it to 0.0. Mine was originally 10.0.
   2b. Global search for IsAutobrightnessOnByDeafult. Mine was in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PolicyManager\default\DispalyEnhancement\IsAutobrightnessOnByDefault. Open up the IsSetting and change the value to 0.0.
3. Reboot.
4. Go back to the device manager and enable the Intel graphics driver.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Intel HD Graphics (4600) on Windows 10 like me, I haven't found *the* solution but I found one I can live with. Increasing the base brightness mostly cancels whatever feature is causing this for me (dark screens getting even darker).

Right-click the Desktop and open 'Graphics Properties..'. With the Intel HD Graphics Control Panel open, go to Display / Color Settings and change the below:
Brightness 55
Contrast 42
Gamma 0.6

Click Apply

Under the 'Video' settings, either choose 'Application Settings' or 'Disable'.