# How to completely turn off adaptive screen brightness based on content?

Tags: windows-10, display, lenovo-laptop, brightness

I have a Lenovo Yoga C940-15IRH (81TE) laptop running Windows 10 that automatically adjusts the brightness of the display based on the content being displayed; however, when the screen displays white content [Wikipedia page], the brightness *increases*, and when the screen displays black content [website in dark mode], the brightness *decreases*.

- This is highly bizarre and the opposite of what I expect - it makes sense to me to decrease brightness when looking at white content, since it's really bright, and to increase brightness when looking at dark content, since it's dark *(not the opposite)*

I want to completely turn off Adaptive Screen Brightness, with the official Windows name being [*Content Adaptive Brightness*](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/content-adaptive-brightness-control-in-windows-292d1f7f-9e02-4b37-a9c8-dab3e1727e78), but apparently this is only for Windows 11, not 10:

- The article explains how to turn it off via *Settings*, but I don't see any of the adaptive brightness options available on my computer

I only notice it happens on battery mode, when my laptop's unplugged.

---

### Bing Chat Solution Tried:

> You can disable Adaptive Brightness on Windows 10 via the command line by opening an elevated Command Prompt and executing the following command:
>
> ```
> powercfg -restoredefaultschemes
> ```

- However, the below links say to instead run:

  ```
  powercfg -setdcvalueindex SCHEME_CURRENT 7516b95f-f776-4464-8c53-06167f40cc99 FBD9AA66-9553-4097-BA44-ED6E9D65EAB8 0
  ```

  - [How to Enable or Disable Adaptive Brightness in Windows 10](https://www.majorgeeks.com/content/page/how_to_enable_or_disable_adaptive_brightness_in_windows_10.html)
  - [How to Turn Off Windows 10 Adaptive Brightness (Fully Disable)](https://windowsloop.com/turn-off-adaptive-brightness-windows-10/)
  - [How to Disable Adaptive Brightness Feature in Windows 10?](https://ugetfix.com/ask/how-to-disable-adaptive-brightness-feature-in-windows-10/)

I ran both commands, but it changed nothing:

```
powercfg -restoredefaultschemes

powercfg -setdcvalueindex SCHEME_CURRENT 7516b95f-f776-4464-8c53-06167f40cc99 FBD9AA66-9553-4097-BA44-ED6E9D65EAB8 0
```

---

### Other Solutions Tried:

- This [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1267850/529800) says to change Registry String Value `ProcAmpBrightness` to `0` within the below key, but I don't have a `profiles` Key:

  ```
  HKLM\Software\Intel\Display\igfxcui\profiles\media\Brighten Movie
  ```

  I only have these keys, but do have DWORD `procAmpBrightness` set to `0` within `MediaKeys`:

  ```
  HKLM\Software\Intel\Display\igfxcui\3D
  HKLM\Software\Intel\Display\igfxcui\MediaKeys
  HKLM\Software\Intel\Display\igfxcui\MISC
  ```
- This [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1643504/529800) says to try changing Adaptive Brightness within the BIOS settings, but my laptop doesn't have this setting

---

I've also tried exhaustively experimenting with the Intel Graphics Command app *(turning off power saver mode, etc.)*, but that didn't do anything, and I'm really out of ideas of what to do.

*Can* Adaptive Brightness even be disabled?

Comment: Is the display HDR capable? If so, the graphics driver settings would likely need to be looked into, as HDR panel manufacturers cheat to obtain HDR by maxing out brightness for bright content and lowering brightness for dark content, thereby effectively creating brighter whites and darker blacks without actually truly implementing the technology.

Comment: If you'd like to give the `profiles` key a shot, save the content from [here](https://pastebin.com/Q4gpki4L) into a text file, then change the extension of the file from `.txt` to `.reg`, open and import it into the Registry

Comment: Update your Intel driver. Be sure to install the ["Intel Graphics Command Center"](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/docs/graphics/graphics-command-center.html) and uninstall other Intel apps (they don't work with current drivers).  Then, in the Command Center, go to `System->Power` and disable `display power savings`.  Also, under `Video`, `Standard Color Correction`should be off. BTW. I have a Yoga C940-15IRH and managed to turn off any adaptive brightness

Comment: addenum to my previous comment. I just remembered: you'll have to first turn power savings ON, then disable any options that before were greyed out, then turn power savings OFF again.

Comment: @1NN, your solution seems to have worked! I installed the Intel Graphics Command Center app whilst on battery power. After I launched the app and verified the settings you mentioned, I restarted my computer. The adaptive brightness seems to have been finally turned off... I will edit my answer with your solution should this apparent fix continue lasting for the next few days.

Comment: @CuriosityCalls I'm glad it works. I've posted it as an answer

Comment: I dont have the settings mentioned.  It seems like every set of instructions ends with me not having the settings.  I tried Command Center, it doesnt have System->Power.  I dont have settings for adaptive brightness.  I dont have anything for Content Adaptive Brightness Control.  Not on 2 laptops, Win10, Win11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Update your Intel driver.
- Install the "[Intel Graphics Command Center](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/docs/graphics/graphics-command-center.html)" and uninstall other Intel apps (they don't work with current drivers).
- While on battery power, open the Graphics Command Center, and go to `System -> Power`. Enable  `display power savings`, then turn off any sub-options which before were greyed out. Then, turn off `display power savings`.
- Also, under the `Video` tab, `Standard Color Correction` should be off.

I have a Yoga C940-15IRH and managed with these steps to turn off the behaviour you describe. But I don't think this solution is limited to that PC model. Rather, OEM display drivers sometimes have strange options turned on, and with the described steps you can reset such behaviours.

Comment: Just for further info: this approach worked. In addition to the other comments I made, I ran the "automatic" driver update tool from Lenovo's website as well as Intel's driver website. After some drivers were installed/updated, the issue seems to have been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

One method that you have not tried is to disable the system service
that is responsible for detecting and taking action for sensor changes.

The Sensor Monitoring Service is responsible for such sensors.
Its description in the Services applet says:

> Monitors various sensors in order to expose data and adapt to system and user state.  If this service is stopped or disabled, the display brightness will not adapt to lighting conditions. Stopping this service may affect other system functionality and features as well.

The sensors it handles are not exactly known. The known ones are
ambient light sensors and screen physical rotation (useful for tablets).

To disable the service :

- Run *Start > Services*
- Locate and click the Sensor Monitoring Service
- Stop the service by clicking the "Stop Service" icon (black square).
  You may at this point test if this solution does disable
  adaptive brightness. If it doesn't help, then this answer does not
  solve the problem. If it does help, continue on.
- Double-click the service entry
- In the service Properties dialog, set the "Startup type:" to
  "Disabled"
- Click OK.

Comment: After reading your answer, I tried this approach, but unfortunately it did not work :(

Comment: Pity that, it was verified as working in several sources... More research needed.

Comment: I tried 1NN's solution in the comments above. That seems to have worked, at least for now. If you'd like to edit your answer to include 1NN's approach, feel free. In one or two days' time, if 1NN's solution continues working, I can accept your modified answer as the final answer.

Comment: No need to, user @1NN has posted his own answer.

Answer (score 0):

For my laptop (also a Lenovo) after trying all of the cmd commands and messing with adaptive brightness the only thing that helped was turning of "Use HDR" in Windows display settings. Hope that's the case for you too.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I made an account on superuser.com just to answer this question. This feature is absolutely awful, but I think I finally found a solution that worked for me.

It appears to be a glitch in the intel graphic command center.

Open this command center, click on system, then click the Power tab. Check every toggle switch 'on', then turn them all off again starting with the bottom (enhanced power saving). I don't know why this worked for me, but it did.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GknKV.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).